# What are the differences between Gaudiya Vaishnavism and the Gaudiya Math lineage?

Tags: vaishnavism, sects, gaudiya-vaishnavism, iskcon

Whenever one writes about Gaudiya Vaishnavism, it is usually only in relation to the Gaudiya Math, founded by Bhaktisiddhanta Saraswati. Gaudiya Math is based on Bhaktivinoda Thakur's interpretations of this teaching. I have often encountered the view that Bhaktivinoda Thakur brought many new elements to the Gaudiya philosophy.

Are there any living Gaudiya traditions based on the Chaitanya teachings, but which function quite independently of the Bhaktivinod Thakur - Bhaktisiddhanta - Bhaktivedanta (ISKCON) lineage?

And what are the differences between them? There are very few sources that I have found.

Comment: Yes there are traditions of Gaudiya Vaishnavism independent of Gaudiya Math. But you wouldn't find them in the Internet. For this you have to come down to the real world & track them.

Comment: The Bhaktivedanta-Bhaktisiddhanta lobby believes that Sri Chaitanya's birthplace isn't in Navadwipa but in Mayapur as discovered by Bhaktivinoda. Tradinitionalist Gaudiya Vaishnavas believe that Sri Chaitanya's birthplace is in Navadwipa, either in Old Mayapur or lost due to erosion caused by the Ganga.

Comment: Traditionalist Gaudiya Vaishnavas attach great importance to the descendents of Sri Chaitanya's companions, notably those from the line of Nityananda & Advaitacharya. This is opposed by the Bhaktivedanta-Bhaktisiddhanta lobby.

Comment: The Bhaktivedanta-Bhaktisiddhanta lobby considers the worship of any deity other than Radha-Krishna to be an act of heresy. Although tradinitionalist Gaudiya Vaishnavas do sometimes sneer upon the worship of other deities, they don't actively discourage their followers from worshipping other deities like the Bhaktivedanta-Bhaktisiddhanta group.

Comment: @AnubrataBit Interesting information. What is the source?

Comment: Gaudiya Math is just one of Gaudiya Vaishnava organisations. *I have often encountered the view that Bhaktivinoda Thakur brought many new elements to Gaudiya philosophy.* I think that's not correct. He did not bring any new elements to Gaudiya philosophy. He followed and faithfully presented original teachings of early Gaudiya Vaishnavas, namely Sri Caitanya Mahaprabhu and his most prominent disciples, Gosvamis, Rupa Gosvami, Sanatana Gosvami, etc.

Comment: @Amritendu Mukhopadhyay Before coming here, I was active on Quora where I came  in contact with the attempts of proselytization by ISKCONites. So I know a little or two about them. Besides you can consult Vanipedia on Internet for Bhaktivedanta's views. Regarding traditionalist Gaudiya Vaishnavas, this is real life experience of mine.

Comment: @AnubrataBit ISKCON people celebrating Shivaratri. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7n1J9j6qYFs

Comment: Lord Shiva once was deep in meditation, but when the beautiful maid Parvati agitated him for sense pleasure, he agreed to the proposal and as a result Kartikeya was born. When Haridas Thakur was a young devotee of the Lord, he was similarly allured by the incarnation of Maya Devi (refering a prostitute); but Haridas easily passed the test because of his unalloyed devotion to Lord Krishna. One who is not, therefore, in Krishna consciousness, however powerful he may be in controlling the senses by artificial repression, is sure ultimately to fall. [Purport of Gita:2:58-62 as explained by him]

Comment: To be more clear the Pashandis (heretics) are those who consider Vishnu in the equal category of Shiva or other demigods. [Interpretation of the word pashanda in Chaitanya Charitamrita:1:3 by him]

Comment: @Amritendu Mukhopadhyay. I can provide you more evidence if you want.

Comment: @AnubrataBit That is true, that Vishnu is the supreme for them. Just like Siva is supreme for Saivas and Devi is supreme for Saktas. But other Gods are also there. They also worship, but as subordinates. That is true for all Hindu denominations. Not only for ISKCON. Think about the condition of Siva in Saktism, mere corpse!

Comment: @AnubrataBit  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kauzr-KsVOg

Comment: @Amritendu Mukhopadhyay From your words, it's clear that you are very much ignorant about Shakta doctrine. I would have liked to engage in a long-drawn discussion with you but due to the word-limit of comments, I am very much reluctant to do so.

Comment: @AnubrataBit In Siva Purana Brahma is described as a lier. and Siva chopped off his 5th head for this sin (using a Bhairava). So as I said, this is true in every Hindu sect. I may be ignorant of Shakta philosophy, I doubt whether you know Hinduism in general at all.

Comment: @Amritendu Mukhopadhyay So what is Hinduism according to you ?

Comment: @AnubrataBit Do not move the goalposts. You are spreading fake information about ISKCON saying it is your personal experience. I have provided two videos as evidence to show that you are wrong. If you have any evidence please provide it.

Comment: If you want to continue the discussion, join this chat https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/131799/room-for-anubrata-amritendu?tab=general

Answer (score 1):

There are more than 64 Lineages in Gaudiya Sampradaya descending from Associates of Mahaprabhu - Like Gadadhar Pandit, Advaita Acharya, Nityananda Prabhu, 6 Goswamis etc.

The lineage of Srila Bhaktivinod Thakur that is Gaudiya Matha & ISKCON are in the Parivaar of Advaita Acharya & their Sanyas Parampara is of Nityananda Prabhu parivaar.

Many other lineages are present mainly in Vrindavan, Bengal, Odisha, Manipur & Rajasthan.

Like Sri Radha Raman Parivaar of Srila Gopal Bhatt Goswami current head is Srila Pundrik Goswami Ji

Gadadhar Parivaar of Srila Gadadhar Pandit current head is Srila Satyanarayan Das Babaji & their institute is known as Jiva Institute

There are various other lineage of other Vaishnavas like Sri Vinod Bihari Babaji, Achyut Lal ji, Prem Gopal Goswami Ji, Ananta Das Babaji etc.

Many Parivaars differ from each other on certain Philosophical & Worshipable aspects however the Mul Siddhanta & Ishta are same.